# EXEC a procedure in an OPENROWSET

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, openrowset

I'm implementing a script that connects in all databases and change subscription options. But, a error occurs here:

```
//...    
FETCH NEXT FROM FILIAL INTO @FIL_CODI, @SERV, @DB, @USR, @PWD;
//...
SET @CON =  "'SQLOLEDB','"+@SERV+"';'"+@USR+"';'"+@PWD+"'"
SET @QUERYORS = "'EXEC sp_changepublication @publication = N''"+@DB+"'', @property = N''replicate_ddl'', @value = 0;'";

SET @QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ('+@CON+','+@QUERYORS+')'
EXEC (@QUERY)
```

Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure ''.

I'm a newbie in SQL

Comment: replace your double quotes with single quotes

Comment: I tried both, but didn't work